# When flutter use webview_flutter opens a webpage, how to use local js to avoid downloading js from the server

Tags: flutter, webview, assets, webview-flutter

We are going to open a web page in the APP, this webpage has 3 js files, a.js b.js c.js, because the a.js file is very large, we are going to download it in advance in the app, when opening the webpage, only download b.js and c.js , a.js uses pre-downloaded (local js) to achieve the purpose of improving the loading speed of web pages.

can this be done?

flutter: 3.10.5
webview_flutter: ^4.2.2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.